# Mapbox: How to continuously wrap a feature layer

Tags: mapbox

Mapbox can continuously wrap tile layers such that you can scroll infinitely to the left and right over a repeating map of the world.

I have added a feature layer to a world map which displays some markers and, for some reason, this feature layer does not also wrap. The markers are only present on the original iteration of the world tiles layer.

I've tried using the `noWrap: false` options property that controls this characteristic on the tile layer when adding a feature layer, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the worldCopyJump option

example:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'your.mapid', {center: [lat, long],
                                                     zoom: 4,
                                                     worldCopyJump: true
                                                    });
```

Comment: This works but it's a very poor solution to the problem at hand. If you're using the map with lots of markers and the international dateline is in the center of the map you will see markers on one half but not the other. As you scroll the map left and right, the map "jumps" (as the name suggests) and marks appear and disappear on either side of the dateline. It's a terrible user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question...

You can use

`maxBounds: [[-90,-180],[90,180]]`

for example

```
map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<some map id>',{minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 10, maxBounds: [[-90,-180],[90,180]]});
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I would have preferred that the feature layer wrap with the world tiles so scrolling wouldn't have to be clamped. As far as I can tell that isn't possible, though.